# Make QuickLook show dynamic icons?

Tags: macos, finder, quicklook

I haven't been able to make Finder use the output of QuickLook plugin as dynamic icons.

IIUC, there are 3 types of Finder file representation:

- 'preview', which can be generated via the plugin's `GeneratePreviewForURL`
- 'thumbnail', which can be generated via the plugin's `GenerateThumbnailForURL`
- 'icon', which what appears in Finder's column view, usually is the same for all files of the same type, but in the case of e.g. images can be a thumbnail of the image ('dynamic icon'), which I presume comes from QuickLook as well.

Now,

- my custom QuickLook plugin seems to generate previews and thumbnails fine, since I've been able to have Finder show them while browsing the filesystem.
- for that, I've registered a custom file type (via a dummy app, since there seems to be no other way to do it).
- but when in column view, Finder keeps showing a blank icon instead of the thumbnail, even though I've selected 'Show thumbnails instead of icons' (the preview pane shows the plugin preview just fine).

Could it be the case that the 'dynamic icon' has to be an embedded thumbnail, rather than something generated by the plugin? But in that case 'dynamic' is a misleading name. As ultima ratio I'd be willing to store a thumbnail, but it would have to be in a resource fork since I just don't want the files to be changed.

Is this just the way it is, or is there something I should be doing? In the registration plist, perhaps?